# Add Pyramid Smartart

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

does any one knows how to add pyramid smartart in powerpoint using  vsto .
I have been searching it but doesn't have any luck. any code in Vba will also help

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  In order to add smartart of a given type, you need to know the index of the smartart type you want to add.  This demonstrates how to add smart art and also gives you a presentation that includes one of each smart art type.  Start with a blank presentation, then delete all slides, including the first.  Then run this:

```
Sub AddSmartArtDemo()

Dim x As Long
Dim oSl As Slide
With ActivePresentation
    For x = 1 To Application.SmartArtLayouts.Count
        Set oSl = .Slides.AddSlide(x, .Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(6))
        oSl.Shapes.AddSmartArt Application.SmartArtLayouts(x)
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

When it completes, slide 1 will have an example of SmartArt index 1, and so on.